# PayPal Payments Advanced: Reject card if AVS or CVV2 or card expiration date check fails

Tags: paypal

What is the method to have the gateway reject a card in the case of an AVS or CSC or card expiration date mismatch?  Right now it will charge a card no matter what with a RESULT code of "0" but AVSADDR returns "N".  I would like it to reject cards when the AVS or CSC or Card expiration date checks fail but not seeing how in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're going to need to enroll for the [PayFlow Fraud Protection Services](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#fraud-protection-service).  Their [PayFlow Fraud Protection Services User Guide](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_payflowpro_fps_guide.pdf) has more detail on setting it up.